# How to get NetBIOS name from IP

Tags: hostname, netbios

My friend has a PC that uses Windows, and I want to know the name of that computer. All I know now is that his IP address is 10.0.0.2, how can I get his computer's name from my Linux box?

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
nmblookup -A 10.0.0.2
```

and then a *grep* ?

Comment: Anyone knows where I can find proper interpretation of that output (what each column is for)?

Comment: Oh, [nm](https://superuser.com/a/710355/44391)

Answer (score 0):

Building on the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170432/22046) provided by [@DaLynX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/51020/dalynx), you could have :

```
function net.ip.netbios.lookup {
    nmblookup -A "$1" | 
    awk 'NR>1 && $1 !~ /MAC/ && $1 && $1 !~ /__MSBROWSE__/ {print $1}' | 
    sort -u
}
```

Which takes you from this

```
$ nmblookup 192.168.211.86
Looking up status of 192.168.211.86
        ITSNOWY         <00> -         B <ACTIVE>
        WORKGROUP       <00> - <GROUP> B <ACTIVE>
        ITSNOWY         <20> -         B <ACTIVE>
        WORKGROUP       <1e> - <GROUP> B <ACTIVE>
        WORKGROUP       <1d> -         B <ACTIVE>
        ..__MSBROWSE__. <01> - <GROUP> B <ACTIVE>

        MAC Address = 08-2E-5F-07-88-19

$
```

To this

```
$ net.ip.netbios.lookup 192.168.211.86
    ITSNOWY
    WORKGROUP
$
```